# how to return a Task<List<string>> via c#?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I'm currently making my first steps with VS2012 and .NET 4.5 with async and await.

for this I'm implementing a method with the following signature:

```
public Task<List<string>> foo() {...}
```

**I know how to return a List but I dont know how to get this list into a Task<>**.
How to do it?

EDIT: here is the complete example, I need to knwo what I need to change to make the return statement possible

```
public async Task<List<string>> foo()
{
    List<string> myList = new List<string>;
        {...}
    return mylist;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your method is actually asynchronous, you can simply add the `async` keyword, and the compiler will generate a `Task` for you.

You can also write asynchronous code by hand, using `ContinueWith()` on an existing task or using the static methods on the `Task` class to create new tasks.

If your method is not asynchronous, there's no point; you should return a `List<string>` directly.
If, for some reason, you *need* to return a pre-completed `Task<T>` from a synchronous method (if you're implementing an interface), you can call `Task.FromResult`.

Comment: or 3) you're using some form of asynchrony other than through `await`, in which case whatever you're using is already generating a task, or some other representation of an async result that you can turn into a task.

Comment: "some other representation of an async result that you can turn into a task" by using `TaskCompletionSource<List<string>>`.

Comment: the question is: how to I write the "return ... myList" to that it will fit to the signature?

Comment: @gurehbgui: Change the signature.  If you can't do that, see my third paragraph.

Comment: So how do I write a method when I want to use `await` to call it, but I don't use `await` inside it? To use `await` when I call it, it must return a `Task` or `Task<T>`. But I should not declare it as `async` if I am not using `await` inside it.

Comment: @Nick: If the method itself is not asynchronous, there is no point in making it pretend to be asynchronous.

Comment: I'm not pretending it's asynchronous. It's a method that does a long running process that I do not want running on the UI thread. There is no method inside of it that I can call with `await`. I want THIS function itself to be called with `await`. According to what you're saying, you should only use `await` on a method that is also using `await` somewhere inside of it (because it's only supposed to be declared as `async` if it contains `await`).

Comment: @Nick: You are completely misunderstanding asynchrony.  Making a method `async` does not affect threads.  You want `Task.Run()`, _outside_ the method.   See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: @Nick: In particular, what I'm saying is exactly correct.  The only point of `await` is to wait for an existing asynchronous operation to finish.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
public Task<List<string>> foo()
{
    return new Task<List<string>>(ReturnList);
}

List<string> ReturnList()
{
    //Do some work
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    //Return the result
    return new List<string>();
}
```

This is not the best practice, however. SLaks' answer covers the async/await possibilities more in detail.

Comment: I'll rewrite my comment. The method `ReturnList` is not complete, you have to write your own code in it, and return a `List<string>`. I edited the method to make it compile.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an asynchronous method use something like:

```
public async Task<List<string>> Testing()
{
    var uri1 = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri1);
        return (await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<string>>());
    }
}
```

see http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4 for a great example.